# Password hash function

Tags: php, function, hash, passwords

Please,

I know this might not meet the requirements of answering questions, 
But I just want to know your opinion on this php password_hash() function.
How safe and secure is it? Are there any flaws? 
I read about it here.

uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: "how secure"? how are we to answer this? We have no idea of what your security requirements are. Security isn't something you can just sprinkle on code like salt on food. More salt does not imply "more secure". just like less salt doesn't imply "less secure" either.

Comment: It's terribly flawed. That's why it made it into the production release.

Comment: @marc just the normal security requirements, am no pro at php security, ok to make it easier, is it preferable to use pbkdf2 or the password_hash().How strong is it against the rainbow attacks. I hope you get what am trying to imply.

Comment: @jihdeh - You are looking for confirmation, be assured that `password_hash()` is "state of the art". It uses a slow key derivation function `BCrypt` which is appropriate to calculate password hashes. Actually it is only a wrapper around the already existing `crypt()` function, but it takes care of all difficult parts, it is so easy to use, that you should forget about other password schemes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password_hash uses bcrypt so here are two takes on using password_hash():

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html

You can choose whether its worth your time or not for your purposes.